# What are the differences between "GTK theme" and "Window theme" in tweak tools?

Tags: 11.10, gnome-tweak-tool, ubuntu-tweak

Both Advanced Settings (gnome-tweak-tool) and Ubuntu Tweak refer to "Window theme" and "GTK theme".  What are the nuances between these two settings?  Where can I find a discussion of this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the difference between a GTK theme, Metacity theme, and Emerald theme?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/51157/what-is-the-difference-between-a-gtk-theme-metacity-theme-and-emerald-theme)

Comment: Not at all a duplicate.  I understand that themes vary among the different windows managers...  What I am trying to figure out is the difference within a specific environment.  For example, I have Ubuntu 11.10, Gnome 3, Gnome Shell.  This is what I use daily.  I have two tools:  Advanced Settings (aka gnome-tweak-tool) and Ubuntu Tweak.  I'm interested in exploring various themes.  With either tool, on its corresponding theme tab it refers to "Window theme" as well as "GTK theme."  I do not know which setting will affect which presentation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The windows theme refers to the buttons at the tops of a window. The gtk theme is the color of the menus , backgrounds, and buttons/dialogs within windows.

[gnome look](http://gnome-look.org/) has additional screenshots and examples.